# How to select the property of an object in a two dimensional array with forEach()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to change the backgound color of a div when clicked depending on a property of the object but I am stuck on how to check the property for each object.

The two dimensional array with total 5x5 25 objects:

```
let tab = [[object{bombe: false}, object{bombe: false}, object{bombe: 
true}, object{bombe: false}, object{bombe: true}], [object{bombe: 
false}, ...
```

Function to create an HTML table and set an ID with 2 numbers to each div:

```
function afficher() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
      let element = document.createElement("div");
      element.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
      element.id = `${i}${j}`;
      document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
    document.write("<br>");
  }
}
```

Add a function that would add a class to a div depending on the 'bombe' property:

```
let cellules = document.querySelectorAll("div");
cellules.forEach(c => c.addEventListener("click", jeu));
 function jeu() {
  if (this.id.bombe) {
   this.setAttribute("class", "red");
   cellules.forEach(c => c.removeEventListener("click", jeu));
  } else {
   this.setAttribute("class", "grey");
 }
}
```

I know that this code will display true or false but this is only for one object ... :

```
let x = tab[0][0].bombe
console.log(x);
```

Any way I can do this with a forEach ?

Comment: Could you clarify which line exactly are you trying to transform ? Is it the content of `afficher()` ?

Comment: It would be this one: `if(this.id.bombe)`, which doesn't work... I want it to say "if the .bombe attribute of the object associated with the case that was clicked on is true" then color the div red in this case. Sorry for my english :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like :

```
function afficher(tab) {
  tab.forEach( (row, i) => {
    row.forEach( (obj, j) => {
       let element = document.createElement("div");
       element.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
       element.id = `${i}${j}`;
       document.body.appendChild(element);
    });
    document.write("<br>");
  });
}
```

> Note that you'll have to pass `tab` as an argument when using `afficher`

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, you wish to apply certain styles to 2d-array of divs based on colormap stored in a variable.
Without employing jQuery, I'd go lazy way: manipulate innerHTML's rather than DOM object and render all at once (within one function).
You might find an example below:

```js
var matrix = [[{attr:false}, {attr:false}, {attr:true}, {attr:false}, {attr:true}],
[{attr:true}, {attr:false}, {attr:false}, {attr:true}, {attr:true}],
[{attr:false}, {attr:true}, {attr:true}, {attr:false}, {attr:false}],
[{attr:false}, {attr:false}, {attr:true}, {attr:false}, {attr:false}],
[{attr:true}, {attr:true}, {attr:false}, {attr:true}, {attr:false}]]

var renderer = (arg) => {
 arg.forEach((row,rownum) => {
  document.querySelector('#box').innerHTML += '<div class="row" rownum="'+rownum+'">';
  row.forEach((cell,cellnum) => {
   let conditionalClass = cell.attr ? 'grey' : 'red';
   document.querySelector('[rownum="'+rownum+'"]').innerHTML += '<div class="cell '+conditionalClass+'" cellnum="'+cellnum+'">'
  });
  document.querySelector('#box').innerHTML += '</div>';
 });

};

renderer(matrix);
```

```css
.row {
    height: 30px;
}
.cell {
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```